# Dynamodb circuit breaker fallback to same global table in different region

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Context :
I have my api gateway in us-east-1 and us-west2 , traffic is expected to come from both regions. I also have a global table setup in us-east-1 and us-west-2. I could get my Write calls simultaneously from both regions which can possibly create race conditions. So I'm writing the item into one dynamo db region in us-east-1, the data gets replicated to us-west-2.

Question:
how can i create a circuit breaker fallback to connect to us-west-2 whenever there is an issue with us-east-1. Is it efficient to maintain 2 dynamodb instances pointing to 2 regions? In that case, one dynamodb instance will always be ideal in normal scenarios.

Comment: @[Alagu Narayanan K] K do you got a chance to solve this issue?